# nginx access.log long comma separated GET requests

Tags: security, nginx, haproxy

I am not sure yet, but I am seeing lots of what looks like attacks using the pagepeeker API (based on the source IP addresses). Granted it could be a problem with my nginx, haproxy load balancer, or php-fpm configurations.

Has anyone seen something similar?  I have removed my domain name and replaced with an example domain in the log example below.

```
144.76.235.110 - - [06/Jul/2014:01:20:15 +0100] "GET /wp-admin/network/,%20https:/www.domain.org/wp-admin/network/,%20https:/www.domain.org/wp-admin/network/,%20https:/www.domain.org/wp-admin/network/,%20https:/www.domain.org/wp-admin/network/,%20https:/www.domain.org/wp-admin/network/,%20https:/www.domain.org/wp-admin/network/ HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"
```

this is one of the virtual host files in question. Have have not seen a re-occurrence of the errors as yet.
NOTE: My SSL termination is done by HAPROXY.

```
server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
  server_name ftmon.org;
  port_in_redirect off;
  return 301 $real_scheme://www.ftmon.org$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
  port_in_redirect off;

  server_name www.ftmon.org;
  root /home/wpmsite/domains/ftmon.org/public_html;
  access_log /home/wpmsite/domains/ftmon.org/logs/access.log main;
  error_log /home/wpmsite/domains/ftmon.org/logs/error.log error;

  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  autoindex off;

  pagespeed on;

  # Allow pagespeed to bypass the load balancer (HAPROXY)
  pagespeed MapOriginDomain http://127.0.0.1:8080 https://www.ftmon.org;
  pagespeed MapOriginDomain http://127.0.0.1:8080 http://www.ftmon.org;

  # Allow pagespeed to bypass nginx
  # pagespeed LoadFromFile http://www.ftmon.org /home/wpmsite/domains/ftmon.org/public_html;
  # pagespeed LoadFromFile https://www.ftmon.org /home/wpmsite/domains/ftmon.org/public_html;


  include /etc/nginx/common/pagespeed.conf;


  # Rewrites for my reset site move to fresh multisite install.
  rewrite ^(/files/)(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/$2 permanent;
  rewrite ^(/wp-content/blogs.dir/22/files/)(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/$2 permanent;
  location / {

    try_files $uri $uri/ @wpmulti @memcached /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  include /etc/nginx/common/locations.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/common/wpcommon.conf;

  #
  # caching solutions
  #
  # include /etc/nginx/common/wordfence.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/common/wpffpc.conf;
}
```

Comment: This look like a bad nginx config with redirect loop. can`y show part of nginx config about this server? (probably /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your_site.conf)

Comment: I have added my virtual host configuration. The include files are quite large. I'll put them on github.

Comment: Github is a good, but where is the link to this file on github?

Comment: UPDATE: rest of config files are [here](https://github.com/dannysheehan/haproxy/issues/1). It includes link to more logs.

Comment: I don\`t understand where, but somewhere there is bad redirect, that contains `, ` (comma with space) maybe in wordpress? try add "$upstream_addr" into log_format to see if request are going to wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by disabling Pagespeed.

`pagespeed off;`

Also, in wordpress I added the following to wp-config.php

`define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
    define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
    define('COOKIEPATH', '');
    define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');`

I might wait for nginx pagespeed code base to stabilize more before revisiting using it again with wordpress multisite when using a network plugin such as network+.

**NOTES**

1. The redirect loop only impacted the main site in multisite wordpress with the network+ plugin installed. The other sites in the multisite were fine.
2. The problem only occurred with thumbnail services (and only with some of them), which made me initially think someone was using these services for attacks.
3. The website thumbnail service was caching pages (even error pages), so it was very difficult to debug and test possible fixes.
4. It's interesting that the redirect loops contained a single / for the http/https redirect addresses i.e. *,%20https:/* rather than *,%20:https//*.